# Define boudned ufunc for log

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to define a function `log_bounded` which is the same as numpy's `log` for positive input, but which gives a big negative number for nonpositive input.  I need it to be a ufunc that can accept an array as input.

So far, I have:

```
def log_bounded(x,verysmall=np.exp(-100)):
    return np.log(np.maximum(x,verysmall))
```

This works,  returning -100 for negative input:

```
>>> log_bounded(2.72)
1.000631880307906
>>> log_bounded(-5)
-100.0
```

But I would like it to return a much lower value, like -10**10.  What I think would be ideal would be something that checks the value of x and directly returns the low value, rather than logging something close to zero, such as

```
def log_bounded_if(x, verylow=-10**10):
    if x > 0:
        return np.log(x)
    else:
        return verylow
```

However, this one doesn't operate element-wise on arrays, since the `if` is trying to run once for the whole array.

Scipy could do the job with `scipy.maximum(scipy.log(x),verylow)`, since `scipy.log` evaluates to negative infinity on a nonpositive input.  However, I need to use numpy because this will run with numba's `autojit`, and scipy seems to eliminate the speed benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via [logical indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

**Minimal solution:**

```py
import numpy as np

def log_bounded(x, verylow=-10**10):
    y = np.log(x)
    y[x <= 0] = verylow
    return y

print log_bounded(np.arange(-2, 3))
```

Output: `[ -1.00000000e+10  -1.00000000e+10  -1.00000000e+10  0  6.93147181e-01]`

---

**More advanced alternative:** (handle scalars as well; save unnecessary `log` computations)

```
import numpy as np

def log_bounded(x, verylow=-10**10):
    if np.isscalar(x):               # handle scalars as well
        if x > 0:
            y = np.log(x)
        else:
            y = verylow
    else:
        y = np.empty_like(x)
        y[x > 0] = np.log(x[x > 0])  # compute log only where needed
        y[x <= 0] = verylow
    return y

print log_bounded(-3), log_bounded(np.arange(-2, 3)), log_bounded(3)
```

Output: `-10000000000 [-10000000000 -10000000000 -10000000000  0  0] 1.09861228867`

Comment: You might as well spare yourself the expensive 'log' operation for the 'verylow' entries: `out = np.empty_like(x, dtype=float); mask = x <= 0; out[mask] = verylow; mask = ~mask; out[mask] = np.log(x[mask]); return out`

Comment: Falko, your solution works on arrays, but throws an error if x is simply a number.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of possible scalar inputs (which aren't of type array). I updated my answer accordingly. By the way I included the suggestion from Jaime. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Falko - your answer is just what I asked for.  Though for reasons I don't yet understand, it loses me the speed boost of numba's autojit, relative to np.log.  (Also, to get it to work at all with numba, I had to remove the keyword argument verylow.)